# Delphi, form release, preventing Application.MessageBox execution

Tags: delphi

so there have been a hundred questions whether to Release vs Free forms in Delphi.
I have encountered an interesting issue that I couldn't explain, below is the (over-simplified) pseudo-code:

```
procedure SomeProc;
var vForm: TForm;
begin
  vForm := create;
  try
    vForm.ShowModal;

  finally
    vForm.Release;
    // more stuff
    Application.MessageBox ('some message');
  end;
end;
```

**expected behavior:**
upon closing my modal form, the messagebox would show up.

**actual behavior:**
Messagebox doesn't show, and execution proceeds as if user pressed 'No' ('No' is the default in the actual code)

**tracing it:**

- ShowModal ends, no problems here
- release is called, CM_RELEASE is posted in the event queue
- MessageBox executes // begin internals of MessageBox code, VCL.Forms unit
- TaskActiveWindow := ActiveWindow; // a handle to the active window is saved. who is the active window?
- MessageBox invokes Application.ProcessMessages
- our modal form destructor is finally invoked.
- external call to Windows, with the saved handle TaskActiveWindow

If the call to Release is replaced by Free, the issue never occurs. Since the form is a Modal (internally, busy looping processing messages), there is no harm in calling Free, so that solves the immediate problem.

However it does not explain what is actually going on under the hood.

I can assume, but cannot prove, that the active window was still the modal form upon saving the handle. And since the handle's underlying form is then freed, this is why the MessageBox is not showing?

Would love some opinions / insights on the above.

PS: copy-pasting this may not reproduce the issue at your end, but what is definitely true is, no issues are faced when calling Free instead of Release.

Comment: Don't call Release here. You call that from inside the form code, if ever you do so. Just Free the form.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, David.  Would you please share some insight as to why that is the way? And is the same applicable to non-modal forms as well?

Comment: `Release` is for use within the form's own methods. It makes sure that all messages have been processed before the form is freed. You should never use it from outside one of the form's methods - use `Free` from code outside those methods. `Free` and `Release` are not the same thing.

Comment: Got it, that makes complete sense.